# what does an 0x8000ffff error mean when adding a pushpin to map.children with windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary

I have a windows phone 7 app that includes a map control.  I am adding a pushpin to keep track of the phone's current location.  I am getting a 0x8000ffff error when I hit map.Children.Add in the following code...

```
                GeoCoordinate co = new GeoCoordinate();
                co.Latitude = location.Latitude;
                co.Longitude = location.Longitude;

                Pushpin pushPin = (Pushpin)map.Children.SingleOrDefault(p => ((Pushpin)p).Name == location.UserToken);
                if (pushPin == null)
                {
                    pushPin = new Pushpin();

                    pushPin.Name = location.UserToken;
                    map.Children.Add(pushPin);
                }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i guess that I should keep debugging before I start asking questions.

It turns out that the location.UserToken is an empty string.  when I specify a non-empty string for location.UserToken the error no longer appears.

I presume that the pushpins are kept in a dictionary via the .Name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting E_UNEXPECTED.  Which is often interpreted to mean, variously, your doing something to an object that is in a state that didn't expect that, or you asked an object to do something with something it didn't expect.  Nice and vague, eh?  The header file (winerror.h) says it means "catastrophic failure", which is a little overkill for this scenario.  They probably should have used E_INVALIDARG.  File a bug via connect.microsoft.com :)